# Can I use white backgrounds while in dark mode in NativeScript apps?

Tags: css, background, nativescript, whitespace

I want to force a white background in my NativeScript application, regardless of the device's theme. However, I haven't found a way to do this. My apps all seem to convert white background colors to dark counterparts when my Android 10 device is in dark mode.

I've tried in new projects, and even the NativeScript playground. Nothing works.

I've added CSS to root elements, disabled forceDarkMode in styles.xml, set everything to use `.ns-light`...the list goes on. Nothing.

Am I missing something? PLEASE tell me I'm missing something.

Comment: You may but it's not recommended. If you are not building your app for dark mode then you could opt of it - https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/dark-mode#dark-mode-for-ios

Comment: I have tried everything in my knowledge as well, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

For iOs Manoj's link works (using `Info.plist` edits) - on Android I had to add this in my `main.ts`:

```
import Theme from '@nativescript/theme';

...

Theme.setMode(Theme.Light);
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong dark mode is disabled by default in Android, one app has to opt in when they want to support dark mode.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not fix the issue for me on Android 10. White is converted to a shade lighter than black.

Comment: Hm, which version of NS and the themes package are you on? I think you need to set the page class to `nt-page` class, but worth a try.

Comment: NativeScript 6.4.2, Theme: 2.3.2. Adding .nt-page didn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you find a solution?